if a run counts if the third out is made before the runner reaches first base
runners on second and third the batter hits it to third.  third baseman tags runner running to third to record the third out of the inning.  during the process the runner from third scores but the batter never reaches first.  does the run count.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

What does "the batter never reaches first" mean?   Just that they didn't reach before other things happened, or that they saw the out and ran back to the dugout instead of touching first base?

Because there are runners on 2nd and 3rd, it is not a force out to tag out R2. So, all that matters is whether or not R3 scores before or after the tag. If R3 scores prior to the tag, the run counts. Otherwise, the 3rd out has been recorded, and the run would not count.
This is not the case if the 3rd out is a force out. So, suppose that it's bases loaded, and R2 is tagged out. In that case, that out is a force out, and regardless of whether or not R3 scores prior to the out, the run would not count.
From the MLB rulebook, Rule 5.08(a) details the requirements for scoring a run.

One run shall be scored each time a runner legally advances to and touches first, second, third and home base before three men are put out to end the inning.
EXCEPTION: A run is not scored if the runner advances to home base during a play in which the third out is made (1) by the batter-runner before he touches first base; (2) by any runner being forced out; or (3) by a preceding runner who is declared out because he failed to touch one of the bases.


I believe this is correct, but are you able to cite the relevant bit of the MLB (or other) rules which support your answer?

@PhilipKendall I've added in a reference to the MLB rulebook detailing how a run is scored.
